# pass data through UnityEvent in event based architecture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm coming from this article

https://unity3d.com/how-to/architect-with-scriptable-objects

and would like to know how to raise an event and pass data to it. Because just listening to this event is not enough. I will try to explain it for reproduction.

First I created a new game event **LevelSceneLoadedGameEvent**

```
class LevelSceneLoadedGameEvent : UnityEvent<Scene> { }
```

When raising this event it should return the current scene that was loaded. Next I created a static **EventManager** to manage all those events

```
public static class EventManager
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, UnityEvent> events = new Dictionary<Type, UnityEvent>()
    {
        {
            typeof(LevelSceneLoadedGameEvent),
            new LevelSceneLoadedGameEvent()
        }
    };

    private static UnityEvent GetEvent<EventType>() where EventType : UnityEvent
    {
        return events[typeof(EventType)];
    }

    public static void SubscribeTo<EventType>(UnityAction listener) where EventType : UnityEvent
    {
        GetEvent<EventType>().AddListener(listener);
    }

    public static void UnsubscribeFrom<EventType>(UnityAction listener) where EventType : UnityEvent
    {
        GetEvent<EventType>().RemoveListener(listener);
    }

    public static void Trigger<EventType>() where EventType : UnityEvent
    {
        GetEvent<EventType>().Invoke();
    }

    public static void Trigger<EventType, FirstParam>(FirstParam firstParam) where EventType : UnityEvent
    {
        GetEvent<EventType>().Invoke(firstParam);
    }
}
```

Other scripts can subsribe / unsubscribe from events and trigger those. Now two problems come up which belong together:

- I can't store my Generic `UnityEvent`s to the dictionary because it's only able to hold non-generic ones

> The best overloaded Add method 'Dictionary.Add(Type,
>   UnityEvent)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments
>   (CS1950) [Assembly-CSharp] Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'LevelSceneLoadedGameEvent' to 'UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent'
>   (CS1503) [Assembly-CSharp]

- My `Trigger` method with one argument fails at `Invoke` because `GetEvent` returns a non-generic `UnityEvent`

> No overload for method 'Invoke' takes 1 arguments (CS1501)
>   [Assembly-CSharp]

How can I fix my **EventManager** to deal with non-generic and generic `UnityEvents`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UnityEvent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) has several generic overloads which you can use to add parameters (such as strings, ints, etc)

Basically any data type Unity will serialize will show up in the inspector.
So you basically need to use a `UnityEvent<string>` for example if you wish to raise an event with a string.

[Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent_1.html) is an example on using the single parameter UnityEvent.

Comment: Thanks. I just found that but then I can't use scriptable objects anymore right? And I would have to create multiple event classes and won't be able to use the inspector anymore ..

Comment: You can use it, no problem. You just need create an instance that inherits, I.E. `SceneLoadedEvent : GameEvent<string>`.

Also, if I answered your question, please mark this as the correct answer, thanks

Comment: I would like to mark it as an answer, but unfortunately it's still not clear to me. I removed my scriptable objects and created two abstract classes `GameEvent` and `GameEvent<T>`. `Raise` now takes `T value` as a parameter. Further I added `OnEventRaised<T>(T value)` but Unity's `Invoke` method takes no parameters. Further I can't assign the events via inspector anymore because they are just classes now... Would you mind explaining it a little more please?

Comment: OK you need to use the generic type to expose the `Invoke<T>` (see here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent_1.html). Regarding classes, anything can be shown on the profiler if you mark the class as `Serializable` and it's private fields as `SerializeField`

Comment: I updated my question and hope this clearifies some things :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by casting the UnityEvent I get from the dictionary to the generic type I want and when adding an event to the dictionary I cast it to UnityEvent. Further I have to use `UnityEventBase` for the dictionary since it's the base class for the events.

Fixed code:

```
public static class GameEventManager
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, UnityEventBase> events = new Dictionary<Type, UnityEventBase>()
    {
        {
            typeof(LevelSceneLoadedGameEvent),
            new LevelSceneLoadedGameEvent()
        }
    };

    private static EventType GetEvent<EventType>() where EventType : UnityEventBase
    {
        UnityEventBase unityEvent = events[typeof(EventType)];
        return (EventType)unityEvent;
    }

    public static void SubscribeTo<EventType>(UnityAction listener) where EventType : UnityEvent
    {
        GetEvent<EventType>().AddListener(listener);
    }

    public static void UnsubscribeFrom<EventType>(UnityAction listener) where EventType : UnityEvent
    {
        GetEvent<EventType>().RemoveListener(listener);
    }

    public static void SubscribeTo<EventType, FirstParam>(UnityAction<FirstParam> listener) where EventType : UnityEvent<FirstParam>
    {
        GetEvent<EventType>().AddListener(listener);
    }

    public static void UnsubscribeFrom<EventType, FirstParam>(UnityAction<FirstParam> listener) where EventType : UnityEvent<FirstParam>
    {
        GetEvent<EventType>().RemoveListener(listener);
    }

    public static void Trigger<EventType>() where EventType : UnityEvent
    {
        GetEvent<EventType>().Invoke();
    }

    public static void Trigger<EventType, FirstParam>(FirstParam firstParam) where EventType : UnityEvent<FirstParam>
    {
        GetEvent<EventType>().Invoke(firstParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't recommend this pattern as you will be unable to create more than one event psr event type. For example if you have multiple places where you wish to call a different type of the same event, this won't be possible.

Comment: Hmm well currently I don't think this is gonna happen but would you suggest a better approach? :) and btw. I will mark your answer as correct

Comment: There are a lot of ways to go about this, it seems you are trying to implement a sort of event bus (or pub/sub https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) - you could add some sort of event filtering. Personally I would consider forcing all events to have exactly one parameter, which inherit from `BaseEventMessage` (equivalent to `EventArgs`) which contain additional info that might be relevant to each event type. This means that for every event type you create a unique event data object